# How to create multiple item list like image

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

[image]

I want to use this mode below to create a list contains another list Like image I n Xamarin form C#
The first item will apears the second list when click on the list item.
and the second list will be hidden when the main list item not clicked.

```
namespace Models
{
    public class AnnouncementListNew : BaseNotifiedModel
    {
        private bool isSelected = true;

        public bool IsItemSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isSelected, value); }
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TitleAr { get; set; }
        public string TitleEn { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public int PublishedDateLong { get; set; }
        public int ExpirationDateLong { get; set; }
        public int ClassificationId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public int Importance { get; set; }
        public string ImportanceName { get; set; }
        public int ResponsibleEntityId { get; set; }
        public bool IsToAllUsers { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public int ExpirationType { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int State { get; set; }
        public string FinalFormAttachmentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public string ClassificationText { get; set; }
        public string TypeText { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDateFormated { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDateStr { get; set; }
        public string EffectiveDateStr { get; set; }
        public string PublishedDateStr { get; set; }
        public string ExpirationDateReportFormat { get; set; }
        public string ExpirationDateStr { get; set; }
        public List<Attachment> Attachments {get; set;}
        public int SourceTypeId { get; set; }
        public RegulatoryDocumentNewCode RegulatoryDocumentCode { get; set; }
        public OrganizationNewCode OrganizationCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attachment : BaseNotifiedModel
    {
        private bool isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isSelected, value); }
        }
        public string RelatedAttachmentID { get; set; }
        public string AttachmentTitle { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public bool IsDraft { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public bool IsSetAsFinalForm { get; set; }
        public int RelatedID { get; set; }
        public int AttachmentModule { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        public string DmsFileId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string RelativePath { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public string UploadDateStr { get; set; }
        public string UploadDateFormat { get; set; }
        public string UploadDateShortFormat { get; set; }
        public string FileIcon { get; set; }
        public ImageSource IconText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to put two list view inside each other and Bindable layout

Comment: You can use the [Xamarin Community Toolkit Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander) to achieve this.